# Узнать, является ли поток бинарным

Tags: c++, файлы

Предположим, что у меня есть поток для записи в файл `ofstream`

```
f(name,ios::binary|ios::in);
```

Можно ли узнать, установлен ли флаг `ios::binary` для этого потока или нет.
Ну или как-то по-другому узнать что это бинарный поток.

Comment: Попробуй `f.flags() & ios::binary != 0`

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags Это вроде не те флаги.

Comment: Похоже, что никак нельзя узнать в каком режиме открыт поток. И это очень странно, что до сих пор не сделаны эти свойства для чтения.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, вы правы. Дошел до компа, и проверил, openmode флаги через flags не добраться. Насколько я понял из объявления классов, до них вообще никак не добраться.

Comment: Придётся самому сделать `ofstream2` с сохранёнными флагами открытия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы быстро всё исправить и все флаги сохранились попробуйте собственную подделку:

```
// g++ fflags.cpp
# include <iostream>
# include <fstream>

namespace Alex {
class ofstream : public std::ofstream{
public:
    std::ios_base::openmode mo ;
    ofstream(const std::string& filename,
      std::ios_base::openmode m):
      std::ofstream(filename,m),mo(m|std::ofstream::out){}
    };
}

void m(Alex::ofstream   & f){
    std::cout<<"ios::binary = ";
    if(f.mo bitand std::ios::binary)        std::cout<<"Ok\n";
    else        std::cout<<"No\n";  }

int main(){
    char const * name = "test";
    Alex::ofstream  f(name,std::ios::binary|std::ios::in); 
    m(f); }
```

>

```
./a.out 
ios::binary = Ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Никак не узнать. И для `std::FILE*` тоже не узнать как был открыт файл.